# Node js pass connection from app.js to insert data

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to node js, I am working with application where there are two connections. Using in single app.. now I want to use the one which is calling from **app.js** and want to remove separate file connection (**db.js**)

Block code from aap.js

```
app.use(
connection(mysql, {

    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    port: 3306, //port mysql
    database: 'testdb'
}, 'request')
);
```

I was using this file to insert data by using separate file connection.

**user_insert.js**

```
var db= require('../db');

http.createServer(function(request, response){

//using this for insert data from ajax 

}).listen(8001);
```

But I want to call **app.js**'s connection for ajax call as well.. How to get connection in a file **user_insert.js** from **app.js** without any major change?

Comment: `app.use()` is for routing. That doesn't look like a routing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use app.set('dbconn', connection) and app.get('dbconn') but there is a bit of a code smell.  A better way would be to pass the connection when you `require` your modules.